# SAPUI5: Filtering doesn't work

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5

I have two json-Mock Files:

Types.json:

```
[{
    "TypeID": 1
}, {
    "TypeID": 2
}]
```

Items.json:

```
[{
    "ItemID": 12345,
    "TypeID": "1",
}, {
    "ItemID": 54321,
    "TypeID": "2",
}]
```

My List Binding:

```
oView.bindElement({
                path : "/Items",
                filters: [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("TypeID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.TypeID) ],
                events : {
                    change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                    dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(true);
                    },
                    dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

My code ignores the filter and shows both Items although only one of them have the right TypeID (1 resp 2). 
Console Output: `oArgs.TypeID` is defined and contains 1 resp 2.

Comment: BindElement is the same as BindContext https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataContextBinding.html#constructor it doesn't have a filters parameter, to filter a collection you need to use a listBinding

Comment: In this case filter is used where control has aggregation items.

Comment: lol thats what i meant, listBinding is for aggregations like tables, not for elements like views, if the code is working you are getting unfiltered data, you havent given us the right code

Answer (score 0):

Element binding is meant for binding UI elements to a specific object in the model data. You are trying to use bindElement to bind UI elements to a set of data.

Because bindElement always binds to a singleton, the filter parameter doesn't make sense and does not exist.